# How to linearize a JSON and make it part of the initial array

Tags: php, arrays, json, performance, optimization

I have an array like the following:

```php
array(
    'session_id'      => 'ea29e7ae5c976794896b4c256f455dd5',
    'user_identifier' => "{'user_id':87,'username':'some username','email':'someuseremail.com','first_name':'Some','last_name':'User','company':'Company'}",
    'request_uri'     => '/'
);
```

And I would like to convert it to the following:

```
array(
    'session_id'  => 'ea29e7ae5c976794896b4c256f455dd5',
    'user_id'     => 87,
    'username'    => 'some username',
    'email'       => 'someuseremail.com',
    'first_name'  => 'Some',
    'last_name'   => 'User',
    'company'     => 'Company',
    'request_uri' => '/'
);
```

Which means I am decoding the JSON at `user_identifier` key and I am making part of the initial array `$original` and then I am removing the `user_identifier` key.

So far this is what I have done:

```php
foreach ($original as $key => $log) {
    $original[$key] = (array) $log;
}

foreach ($original as $key => $log) {
    foreach($log as $k => $v) {
        if ($k === 'user_identifier') {
            $original['decoded'] = (array) json_decode($v);
        }
    }
}
```

Which is giving me an array like this one:

```
array(
    'session_id'  => 'ea29e7ae5c976794896b4c256f455dd5',
    'request_uri' => '/',
    'user_identifier' => "{'user_id':87,'username':'some username','email':'someuseremail.com','first_name':'Some','last_name':'User','company':'Company'}",
    'decoded' => array(
        'user_id'     => 87,
        'username'    => 'some username',
        'email'       => 'someuseremail.com',
        'first_name'  => 'Some',
        'last_name'   => 'User',
        'company'     => 'Company'
    )
);
```

As you may notice this is not even the array I am looking for and I have already  one `foreach` loop to convert the initial result to an array - it's coming as and `stdClass` object - and then a nested `foreach` loop for decode the JSON and try to make it part of the initial array.

In such case I will need to add another loop to linearize the array. My concern is this array is just an example but the one I need to convert is a big one.

Is there any better way to achieve this?

I am using PHP 5.3.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this:

1. Extract the JSON from the original into an array. (Be sure to set the second argument of `json_decode` so you end up with an array instead of an object.)

   ```
   $identifier = json_decode($your_array['user_identifier'], true);
   ```
2. merge the extracted array with the original.

   ```
   $your_array = array_merge($your_array, $identifier);
   ```
3. Unset the now-redundant JSON

   ```
   unset($your_array['user_identifier']);
   ```